# Complete filling below a plot

Tags: plotting

We want to fill a part of below of a plot which is brought here as

```
Show[Plot[
 10^-29/((E^(10^-6/x) - 1) x^5), {x, 0.0000000001, 0.000001}], 
 Plot[10^-29/((E^(10^-6/x) - 1) x^5), {x, 4*10^-7, 6*10^-7}, 
  Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All]]
```

Unfortunately the highlighted region (filled area) is not extended completely up to the `x` axis (`y=0`). How can we solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: Include `AxesOrigin->{0,0}` in the second plot.

Comment: Try also `Filling -> 0`.

Answer (score 2):

As per @CarlWoll's comment, the quickest way to achieve this is to include `AxesOrigin -> {0,0}` in the second plot:

```
Show[
 Plot[10^-29/((E^(10^-6/x) - 1) x^5), {x, 0.0000000001, 0.000001}],
 Plot[10^-29/((E^(10^-6/x) - 1) x^5), {x, 4*10^-7, 6*10^-7}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
]
```

[image]

The reason for the original code only shading part of the plot is that the original second plot, considered on its own, only shows a fraction of the combined plot's area, and so its axes are not the 'usual' axes centred at (0,0):

[image]